# Creating desktop icons in LUBUNTU 20.04 LTS , using LXQT -problems making launchable

Tags: lubuntu, launcher, icons, lxqt, editing

I recently upgraded my LUBUNTU 18.04 to 20.04LTS that uses LXQT for its desktop. All my desktop shortcuts (*.desktop files) are unlaunchable. Previous people have posted similar questions for UBUNTU 20.04 and have suggested right-clicking on the icon and selecting "Enable launching".  However on my installation this is not present.

I can still launch but awkwardly, by double clicking which brings up another dialog window asking whether to execute it or to open it with the "shortcut editor".

Any ideas as to how this extra step can be eliminated?  Why does it happen in Lubuntu but not in Ubuntu?

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last release using LXDE, thus upgrade from that release to a LXQt release is unsupported & not recommended. The release notes for Lubuntu 20.04.1 state (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"  Upgrade was possible yes, but *repairs* needed vary on packages etc installed.

Comment: As to differences with Ubuntu and Lubuntu; Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04 both used GNOME, which differs to Lubuntu 18.04's use of LXDE, and Lubuntu 20.04's use of modern LXQt. You mention three different desktops, and whilst LXQt is very similar to LXDE, it also contains components from RazorQt (LXDE team joined with LXDE creating LXQt).  The Lubuntu manual page for desktop icons can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html

Comment: Did you upgrade with a fresh install like recommended?

Comment: Yep. Didnt help at all. This reminds me of early Microsoft days. Waste of time.  I may downgrade back to a fresh install of Lubuntu 18.04LTS until the 20.04 release team cures some of the window manager problems. Its almost a dog's breakfast right now.

Comment: `openbox` (which is the window manager) is the ~same, both *stable* for both 18.04 (LXDE) & 20.04 (LXQt) with almost no changes at all (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/o/openbox/openbox_3.6.1-9/changelog).  18.04 reaches EOL in April-2021 (when it's 3 years from release as it's a *flavor*). Upgrading was **not** recommend due to problems; the team said to install fresh to avoid issues (LXDE configs can impact LXQt), but it's a **different* desktop, with ideas from Razor-Qt, so not everything works the same as LXDE which is intentional.  LXDE relied on depreciated GTK2

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in comments, the differences between Lubuntu 18.04 and Lubuntu 20.04 are drastic due to the new desktop environment.

If you read the [release](https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) [notes](https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/) for Lubuntu 20.04, you will see the following note under "Support":

> Due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop
> environments, **the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04**
> or below to any greater release. **Doing so will result in a broken
> system**. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, **please
> do a fresh install**.

Your best path to "upgrade" to Lubuntu 20.04 isn't really an upgrade at all.  You should [download Lubuntu 20.04 installation media](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) and install Lubuntu 20.04 cleanly from the external installation media.  For best results, format (erase) your hard drive ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Click the bird menu drag a application from there to desired place, select copy here. Right click the icon -> tick trust this executable.